# core-compact but not locally compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, locally-compact-groups

A space $X$ is called core-compact if the set of all open set in $X, \mathcal{O}(X)$, is a continuous poset.

It is known that every locally compact is core-compact.

Here, a space $X$ is locally compact if every $x\in X$ and every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a compact neighbourhood of $x$.

I am looking an example of core-compact but not locally compact.

I am thinking $\mathcal{R}$ with co-countable topology. This space is not locally compact.

For any  $U\in\mathcal{O}(R)$, $U\neq\sup\{V: V\ll U\}$, where $V\ll U$ means every open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $U$ there is a finite subcover of $V$. Indeed, since for every  $U\in\mathcal{O}(R)$, $\{V: V\ll U\}=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

I only saw this question today; it is indeed hard to find examples of this sort of thing.

A somewhat elaborate example, essentially the spectrum of the distributive continuous lattice of lower semicontinuous functions $I \to I$ on the unit interval (where elements of the spectrum are prime elements of the lattice), is given in [The Spectral Theory of Distributive Continuous Lattices](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1978-246-00/S0002-9947-1978-0515540-7/S0002-9947-1978-0515540-7.pdf) by Hofmann and Lawson, section 7.

Unfortunately, your co-countable topology example isn't core-compact. Indeed, for the maximal open $\mathbb{R}$ in this topology, there is no nonempty open $W$ satisfying $W \ll \mathbb{R}$. For, such $W$ contains an infinite countable set $A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots \}$, and then the sets $\{a_n\} \cup (\mathbb{R} \setminus A)$ form an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$ with no finite subcover of $W$. This example appears on page 9 of [this report](http://vrs.amsi.org.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2016/03/Michael-Hallam-Report.pdf).

Comment: Just to comment that the space constructed by Hofmann-Lawson is core compact, and yet still has the absolutely bonkers property that the interior of every compact subset is empty.